# Restore a whatsapp chat with someone else using that person's phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have lost my phone and got a new one. Unfortunately I did not backup my WhatsApp.
There is a chat session held between me and someone else which is very dear to me. I have this person's phone.
I wonder if I can restore this chat on my phone through that other person's phone.
Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I don't believe it is possible since AFAIK database backups are signed with an account specific key.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use the 'email chat' option. This would send you a copy of the conversation to your email.

Open the chat on your friends phone,
Press on the menu on the top right>more>email chat. Put in your email address, and you will have a copy of the conversation.

There is no way to port the conversation over to WhatsApp and make it appear as if you never lost it. Unless you have a backup.